# How to do Parquet writing on Hadoop 2.6?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We want to write Parquet files.

I tried streaming file sink but it doesn't support Hadoop 2.6 because it depends on HDFS.truncate - however a lot of folk and enterprises will still be using 2.6.

So we tried the Avro bucketing sink and started writing a Parquet writer based on AvroKeyValueSinkWriter and then fell over the problem discussed in FLINK-10382. See my comments about Flink QA .

We can see that AvroKeyValueSinkWriter compensates for the lack of truncate by using file rewriting which is a reasonably common practice.

Not clear why the streaming file sync gives up when HDFS.truncate isn't present rather than falling back on the file rewrite scheme.

Anyway - am I forced to write my own Parquet support or is there a better way?

Comment: See PR: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/6608

Comment: Yeah clearly that's not an actual solution. But thanks. Seems flink is still ignoring those of us stuck on 2.6

Comment: I think they are targeting Kubernetes more and more. And as Stephan said in the comment - in the sake of the code clarity they want simply use truncate function.